# r shiny create a dropdown from a column of data in csv

Tags: r, csv, shiny

My dropdown menu right now is populating with the column names. Instead, i want to create a dropdown that simply uses everything in the first column as the options. can anyone help with my output$toCol function?

server.R:

```
filedata <- reactive({
  infile <- input$datafile
  if (is.null(infile)) {
  # User has not uploaded a file yet
   return(NULL)
  }
  read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE)
})

output$toCol <- renderUI({
  df <-filedata()
  if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)

  items=names(df)
  names(items)=items
  selectInput("species-dropdown", "Species:",items)
})
```

ui.R

```
fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file', accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
uiOutput("toCol")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, instead of `if (...) return(NULL)` use `req` which will raise an a "silent" exception if `input$datafile` is NULL and it will prevent propagation of the errors. It will simplify your code and it is a very good practice to use it. See also `validate` and `need`.

The answer to your question is as simple as this:

```
    df <- filedata()
    # as.character: to get names of levels and not a numbers as choices in case of factors
    items <- as.character(df[[1]])
    selectInput("species-dropdown", "Species:", items)
```

I also added a [small interface](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html) for uploading files.

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)
rm(ui)
rm(server)

server <- function(input, output) { 

  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    # require that infile is not NULL (?req)
    # it will prevent propagating errors 
    req(infile) 

    # read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    iris
  })

  output$toCol <- renderUI({
    df <- filedata()

    # as.character: to get names of levels and not a numbers as choices in case of factors
    items <- as.character(df[[1]])

    selectInput("species-dropdown", "Species:", items)
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  # http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
      radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                   c(Comma=',',
                     Semicolon=';',
                     Tab='\t'),
                   ','),
      radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                   c(None='',
                     'Double Quote'='"',
                     'Single Quote'="'"),
                   '"')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("toCol")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much! I'm really new to shiny, so i'm clearly not well versed in best practices yet. Or writing simple code

Comment: You should take a look at [these](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/) articles and especially `Best practices` part :)  It is the best place to start (after an official tutorial) :)